# Table of Directories with Checkboxes (php/html)

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm working toward creating website that lists all the files within a directory with a checkbox option, and if the checkbox is selected, an html submit button will run a python script to organize the contents of the file.

Right now I have a table of files with checkboxes, but I am having trouble connecting a marked checkbox with the proper file. Here's what I have:

```
<?php

$myDirectory = opendir(".");

//items don't want listed
$blacklist = array(".", "..", 'test.php'); 

while(false !== ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))) {
    if (!in_array($entryName, $blacklist)) {
        $dirArray[] = $entryName;
        //echo "$entryName\n";
    }
}

closedir($myDirectory);

//count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);

//print table
echo ("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class= whitelinks>\n");
echo ("<TR><TH>CheckBox</TH><th>File Name</th></TR>\n");

// loop through array of files and print them all
for ($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".") { //dont list hidden files 
        echo("<TR><TD><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"comp[]\" value=\"$dirArray[$index]\"</td>");
        echo("<td>");
        echo("<a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
        echo("</TR>\n");
    }
}
echo("</TABLE>\n");    
?>
```

So just for now, how do I connect the marked checkboxes to the proper directory and check with a submit button with form action to a `php` file to display which companies I have marked?

Comment: Let me get this straight, if a user **checked** a checkbox and submitted the form you want the server to render a list of files/folders for the user?

Comment: @odedta yeah, just for now to make sure that the checkboxes are associating with the proper directory.

Comment: use `if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) { // show these folders }`

Comment: @odedta Would I put this in a separate `php` file and then call it by form action, or would I place that below what I have?